# Referencing an associative array added as value inside another associative array

Tags: php, arrays, reference, associative-array

I have the following structure:

```
$positions = array();
$salaries = array();

$registers = ['Position' => $positions, 'Salary' => $salaries];
```

Since I created the positions and salaries associative arrays at the beginning using the array() syntax I assumed that later in the code I can just write:

```
$salaries += [$name => $salary];
```

But found out that at the end when tried to get some data using the registers array:
`$registers['Position']` or `$registers['Salary']` after I've done some filtering everything was empty and I had to reference it via registers to actually put data in:

```
$registers['Salary'] += [$name => $salary];
```

or create the registers array later in the code near the end of the script when the other arrays - positions and salaries were already full with the needed data.

My question is - since I put positions and salaries as values inside registers array does that mean I lose the ability to reference them as separate / independent arrays. I created them as described with that purpose in mind and registers array is for filtering purposes  and I made it at the beginning so I have all that code at the very top of the script.

Will be very grateful for any info on the matter.

Comment: `$registers = ['Position' => $positions, 'Salary' => $salaries];` simply creates _copies_ of the current content of those arrays at this point. What you want, would require that the elements be added as _references_ instead of copies: `$registers = ['Position' => &$positions, 'Salary' => &$salaries];` But there are some cave-ats when working with references, so make sure you understand what is explained under https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php properly.

Comment: @CBroe worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Will read what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)'s comment as an answer for better visibility.

---

`$registers = ['Position' => $positions, 'Salary' => $salaries];` simply creates copies of the current content of those arrays at this point. What you want, would require that the elements be added as references instead of copies: `$registers = ['Position' => &$positions, 'Salary' => &$salaries];` But there are some cave-ats when working with references, so make sure you understand what is explained under [php.net/manual/en/language.references.php](https://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) properly.